# Smooth frame moving animation in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Im using a sprite sheet in javascript/css and something I wanted to do was use the same 3 frames (the sprite walking) infinite times until it reaches the 100% mark.

This is what I am doing in css:

```
.WomenAnimation{
    animation: moveGirl 3s steps(30) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: moveGirl 3s steps(30) infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveGirl 3s steps(30) infinite;
    -ms-animation: moveGirl 3s steps(30) infinite;
    -o-animation: moveGirl 3s steps(30) infinite;
}

@keyframes moveGirl {
   from { background-position: -600px; left:240px}
     to { background-position: -1200px; left:750px}
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveGirl {
   from { background-position: -600px; left:240px}
     to { background-position: -1200px; left:750px}
}

@-moz-keyframes moveGirl {
   from { background-position: -600px; left:240px}
     to { background-position: -1200px; left:750px}
}

@-ms-keyframes moveGirl {
   from { background-position: -600px; left:240px}
     to { background-position: -1200px; left:750px}
}

@-o-keyframes moveGirl {
   from { background-position: -600px; left:240px}
     to { background-position: -1200px; left:750px}
}
```

So as you can see I'm trying to move it across the screen in 3 seconds trying to make it look smooth, but what I get is the sprite teleporting and doing some weird movements.

Edit:

Here is the female sprite so you can try to move her across the div. 
As well as the div in the html and some css that goes along with it.

```
#bg{
    width:640px;
    height:500px;
}

#WomenSprite{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
position:absolute;
background-image:url("http://imageshack.com/a/img14/3948/z5pt.png");
```

}

```
<div id="bg">
    <div id="WomenSprite"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are assigning `moveGirl` to the `animation` property but have named the keyframes as `playGirl`

Comment: Ah yea, that was en edit I made for stackoverflow, didn't want people thinking differently.

Comment: can you post a live example so we can tinker with it ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I have edited it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `steps` property of your animation;

```
 animation: moveGirl 3s steps(30) infinite;
```

**`steps(30)`** is causing the problem.

**Example:**

[**Fiddle** (no steps)](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/u9QCw/)
[**Fiddle** (steps)](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/u9QCw/1/)

---

### EDIT

Thanks for **@Gaby aka G. Petrioli** for pointing out the real problem.

So, as you are using a sprite with animation parts, and also a position animation, you need to have 2 animations. One with the `steps(30)` and also background-position, and another one with just the `div` animation.

Something like this:

```
.WomenAnimation {
    -webkit-animation:
         moveGirl1 3s linear infinite ,
         moveGirl2 3s steps(30) infinite ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveGirl1 {
   from { left:240px; }
     to { left:750px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveGirl2 {
   from { background-position: -600px; }
     to { background-position: -1200px; }
}
```

This way `moveGirl1`  is going to be linear and fluid, and `moveGirl2` is going to be stepped, as it is the sprite positions.

---

Here is the final code working:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/FVGYq/1/)**

Comment: I tried this but it still gives me the same result. '

Comment: can you see the examples I've provided?

Comment: @ToniAlmeida the OP said he is using a sprite.. so the animation should be in distinct steps to go to specific sprite parts..

Comment: @ToniAlmeida I've provided some code and the sprite itself so you can mess around with it.

Comment: @ToniAlmeida question, do you know how I make it so that at the end of the animation it doesn't go back to the first frame?

Comment: Yes! you can add the `forwards` atribute so it will stop at the last frame of your animation. `moveGirl1 2s linear 1 forwards,`. I've also changed the `infinite` to `1`, so it will only run once.